# Controlled React input, which one is more efficient: change state immediately or setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app has many input fields, and most of them are controlled by state.

Resetting state everytime the value of input changes cause the page to re-render which may slow down the app (correct me if I was wrong).

So I don't want React to reset state every time the input changes; instead, change the state a few seconds after user stops inputting.

So I created a `LaggedTextField` with `setTimeout`:

```js
const LagTextField = ({ delay, onChange, value, ...props }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    localValue: "",
    timer: null,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ localValue: value, timer: null });
  }, [value]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(state.timer);
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;
    setState({
      localValue: value,
      timer: setTimeout(() => {
        triggerChange(value);
      }, delay),
    });
  };

  const triggerChange = (value) => {
    onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onFocus={selectOnFocus ? handleFocus : null}
      value={state.localValue}
    />
  );
};
```

Before I replace all inputs to this component, I need to make a few thing clear:

1. Is normal controlled input changes cause the whole page to re-render?
2. Is this lagged input (`setTimeout`) more efficient than a normal controlled input?

Comment: React has optimized rendering, you dont need to setTimeout.  google `react fiber` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about react. One of the biggest benefits of react is that it only changes that part in a page which experiences any change (from user or any other source). So you don't need to worry about that.

Also this is the reason which makes react really fast.

When new elements are added to the UI, a virtual DOM, which is represented as a tree is created. Each element is a node on this tree. If the state of any of these elements changes, a new virtual DOM tree is created. This tree is then compared or “diffed” with the previous virtual DOM tree.

Once this is done, the virtual DOM calculates the best possible method to make these changes to the real DOM. This ensures that there are minimal operations on the real DOM. Hence, reducing the performance cost of updating the real DOM. Get more info [Here](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-virtual-dom-explained/)

Comment: But sometimes in a page that renders a big form and complex contents, all inputs and selects and all other form fields are conrolled by a single state: `{name:"...", "address": "...", ...}`. Without my lagged textfield, the page feels heavy when I press down some key to make input value changes continuously. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As @Ayushi keshri suggested to wrap them in a form and control the form submission by a button, that is also a good choice but if you don't want to do that, i think you are doing fine. Setting some timeout is a good way. I used this method in a search bar functionality where related searches were shown on the basis of input. So i also set some time gap between new checks and there it was working fine.

Comment: And of course, react is better doesn't mean it will handle everything, changing the things again and again just because the input field is changing doesn't make too much sense as no user will be done just after every key press. The user must be typing some long string and waiting for that by using SetTimeout is a good choice.

Comment: So `setTimeout` or not almost has no (good / bad) effect? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but i think you are not getting me. I said that your way (i.e, setTimeout) is a good choice and it will affect the rendering. Not setting some timeout is not a good choice as the function will be invoked again and again after each key stroke which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are taking inputs from the user, trying enclosing all your fields in the form and on form submit to try to call the change Handler, this way on every keypress the dom is not going to get updated (eventhough it do update the virtual dom and not real dom) and remember to `e.preventDefault()` in your submit handler to prevent the form default behaviour of redirecting to different page.

This shall reduce some regression on browser though it might not affect the performance but might reduce some overhead.